# illegal Argument Exception from TextView android

Tags: android, textview

The error I got from the log is `Error inflating class TextView Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create internal object. maybe invalid font data`

This happens in the `SplashActivity` in that layout file with the name of `activity_splash.xml` and it has TextView in it. If I remove the remove the TextView block the app runs fine but on further run if any activities that used TextView this crash occurs.

The crash log says maybe invalid font data but I don't use custom fonts for SplashScreen or for most of the text views. I only use custom font for some Dialogs and I added fonts inside  res/font/ folder.

Help would be much appriciated.

Comment: Well, this comes from when minikin rejects the font for some reason. Do you have some font defined in your app theme?

Comment: Nothing in App theme but have a button style that refers another theme that has fontFamily in it. But the font is actually present in the res/font/fontname.ttf folder tho.

Comment: Well you're most certainly correct, I just tried to remove fontFamily references of themes from App theme and no crash now. Do you know any reasons for this? Maybe this is due to the fact that fontFamily referred from another style component? Thanks a ton for the help in pointing out this.